# Updating map type model in Mobx State Tree is causing memory leak

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

In my store I am updating my model like this. With every update the memosry consumption is increase by several times

Here is my code which is causing memory leak:

```
 self.employees.set(empId, EmployeeMode.create({...empData}));
```

self.employees is of Type map.

I've tried few things like setting directly `self.employees.set(empId, status)` , `self.employees.set(empId, {})` but these two things aren't fixing the memory leak.

I believe whatever I do there will always be memory leak.
Suppose there is some object corresponding to id 'zyz' and after new API I update the 'xyz' with new object. Now the old object is still in memory. And with each new API call its count will increase.

It would be great help if someone point me right direction about the cause.

Comment: `but nothing is working` what is not working exactly? `memosry consumption is increase by several times` maybe you could provide more info, some sort of screenshot or numbers, how big is this leak? Maybe reproduce this part of store at http://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: @Danila I've updated my question with some additional details.